# Slow AD group sync

Tags: active-directory, ldap

We are writing software tool that allows Active Directory authentication mechanism. It periodically syncs user groups between AD and the tool. Some of our customers have observed that during the sync operation there is high cpu load on AD servers.

I searched for possible reasons which may cause the problem. One of them is nested groups.

Also I have found in the Internet that other people have had such problems too and when they changed AD port the problem has disappeared. I would like to know if the last scenario is realistic (it is a bit strange for me that changing AD port may solve the problem) and if there are other common reasons that may cause the problem.

We use the following query to sync:

```
(&(memberof:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=group_DN)(objectclass=u‌​ser)(!(objectclass=c‌​omputer))
```

Comment: No, this will not solve the problem. And it will likely *cause* additional problems for your customers.

Comment: Maybe you should tell us how your tool syncs group information. How is it doing that exactly?

Comment: There's not enough detail here to offer a useful answer. I'm struggling to understand how "Changing the AD port" would improve anything. You mention "nested groups", which immediately makes me wonder how your tool deals with circular nestings.

Comment: It just queries all the users for a group, using the following query: (&(memberof:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=group_DN)(objectclass=user)(!(objectclass=computer))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turned out that the problem indeed was with nested groups. I "moved" the recursion logic to the client side and it reduced run time ~10 times. I don't know how much is network traffic going to increase. Anyway here is the code snippet that I used, in case, if someone is interested:

```
public Set<String> getUsersInGroup(String groupDN) throws NamingException {
    Set<String> ret = new HashSet<>();
    Queue<String> bfsQueue = new LinkedList<>();
    bfsQueue.add(groupDN);
    Set<String> visitedGroups = new HashSet<>();
    LdapContext ctx = getLdapContext(MAX_SEARCH_TIME, false);
    String[] attrIDs = getUserReturnAttrs().toArray(new String[0]);
    while (!bfsQueue.isEmpty()) {
        String current = bfsQueue.element();
        bfsQueue.remove();
        visitedGroups.add(current);

        String userFilter = "(&(objectclass=user)(!(objectclass=computer)))";
        String groupFilter = "(&(objectclass=group)(!(objectclass=computer)))";
        String memberOfFilter = String.format("(memberof=%s)", current);
        String userQuery = String.format("(&%s%s)", memberOfFilter, userFilter);
        String groupQuery = String.format("(&%s%s)", memberOfFilter, groupFilter);

        Set<SearchResult> groups = search(ctx, getSearchBase(), groupQuery, SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE,
                new String[] { "distinguishedName" }, NO_COUNT_LIMIT);
        for (SearchResult g : groups) {
            Attributes attrs = g.getAttributes();
            String gDN = parseAttribute(attrs, "distinguishedName");
            if (!visitedGroups.contains(gDN)) bfsQueue.add(gDN);
        }

        Set<SearchResult> users = search(ctx, getSearchBase(), userQuery, SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE,
                attrIDs, NO_COUNT_LIMIT);
        for (SearchResult u : users) {
            Attributes attrs = u.getAttributes();
            String uDN = parseAttribute(attrs, "userPrincipalName");
            ret.add(uDN);
        }

    }
    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't use the LDAP matching rule transitive evaluation for recursive group membership. It is notoriously slow, particularly with large directories/group memberships.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40024425/1-2-840-113556-1-4-1941-ldap-matching-rule-in-chain-has-performance-problems

http://dunnry.com/blog/TransitiveLinkValueFilterEvaluation.aspx

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9534669/improving-recursive-active-directory-function

Comment: OK, but what are the alternatives to get all users of a group (including nested groups) ?

Comment: `import-module activedirectory`  
`Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "CN=Administrators,CN=Builtin,DC=contoso,DC=com" -Recursive | Get-ADUser -Properties displayname, name`